# kotlin rem operator doesn't give me correct answer

Tags: kotlin, floating-point, operators, precision

I use remainder inside my code with kotlin in android project but with this value I don't get the correct answer.

variable is :

```
 val vv = 1529.71
 val ratio = 0.01
 val remainder = vv.rem(ratio)
```

it's must be **zero** but **remainder** value is :
`4.5363018896793506E-15`

I don't understand why this happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is because `vv` isn't actually 1529.71 but the closest possible `Double`, the exact value is 1529.7100000000000363797880709171295166015625 (the easiest way to see it is `println(java.math.BigDecimal(vv))`). If you want to represent decimal numbers exactly, use `BigDecimal` and pass the fraction as a string:

```
val vv = BigDecimal("1529.71")
val ratio = BigDecimal("0.01")
val remainder = vv.rem(ratio)
```

Read more about floating point here: https://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: thanks for Your suggested link, I don't know about it.. I try it soon..

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i had to get only the exact digits of two numbers after the decimal point.
I achieved it by doing this:

```
val input = 30.47f
val remainder = (input * 100).toInt() - (input.toInt() * 100)
// remainder = 47 exactly, and not 469999999...
```

Hope this would be helpful for someone.